# Probability whether all characters would appear at least once?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I'm generating a random string of length $n$ over the English alphabet, what is the probability that each character from the English alphabet would appear at least once?  Assume $n \geq 26$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is
$$\frac{26!S(n,26)}{26^n}$$
where $S(n,k)$ denotes a Stirling number of the second kind. This is because the collection of length $n$ strings of $26$ letters where each letter occurs at least once corresponds to the set of ordered partitions
of an $n$-element set into $26$ nonempty subsets. This is $26!$ times
as large as the collection of unordered partitions
of an $n$-element set into $26$ nonempty subsets. Those partitions are counted by the Stirling number $S(n,26)$.

Comment: @SoloNasus Please accept this answer instead (given that it actually turns out be correct, I wouldn't know), so I can delete my erroneous post.